# knowing if a excel is having any columns or not in POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating a excel using apache POI.

There would always be headers as the first row.

Based on the logic, there could be data rows or not.

As the end step, I am mailing the generated report.

However, I do not want to send empty file in the mail.

Is there a method which checks for the rows and returns the number of rows in the generated excel. So that I can have that condition used to decide whether to mail the report or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Worksheet.getLastRowNum()` will return the last row count. You may able to use to see if you any 'real data'.

(IMHO, not generating the file may be more useful approach)